# Laravel Form validation with logic operators

Tags: forms, validation, request, laravel-5, rules

When a user fill Message (textarea) he/she can't fill Date,Time,Venue values.
Those three fields will consider only when Message is empty and all those three fields are filled.
How to do this using Laravel form validation? Is it possible to define these logic in Request's rule method?
I am new for Laravel.
Thanks in advance

[image: This is my form]

Comment: So you want either message field filled by user or only those three fields. But not all four of them together? Anyone requirement to be fullfiled?

Comment: Yes, not all four together.

Answer (score 5):

You can achieve this (serverside) by using conditional validation rules:

- required_if:anotherfield,value,...
- required_unless:anotherfield,value,...
- required_with:foo,bar,...
- required_with_all:foo,bar,...
- required_without:foo,bar,...
- required_without_all:foo,bar,...

I would say for your case:

- *date* is required unless message is filled-in
- *time* is required unless message is filled-in
- *venue* is required unless message is filled-in
- *message* is required without all *date, time, venue*

Chain rules if you need by separating them with pipe

Follows an example snippet. Use this method inside your *ExampleFormRequest* extending `Request`

```
/**
 * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
 *
 * @return array
 */
public function rules()
{
    $rules = [];

    switch ($this->method()) {
        case 'PATCH':
        case 'PUT':
        case 'POST':
            $rules = [
                'date'    => 'required_without:message',
                'time'    => 'required_without:message',
                'venue'   => 'required_without:message',
                'message' => 'required_without_all:date,time,venue',
                ];
            break;
        default:
            // Perform no alteration to rules
            break;
    }

    return $rules;
}
```

Checkout [documentation here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/validation#rule-required-if)

Comment: InvalidArgumentException in Validator.php line 2999:
Validation rule required_unless requires at least 2 parameters.

Comment: @Sachith You are right, sorry. Ive changed the rules, it should be required_without instead required_unless, as the former does not evaluate value, just presence.

Comment: I had tried updated answer, nothing.still getting the both.

Comment: Can you post the exception? It cant be `required_unless` again... which is it exactly?

Comment: No, this time, no errors shown, redirected to the page,but without any data.

Comment: So, the symptom changed. What are saying your logs? It seems to be a redirect without feedback or an Exception somewhere we dont see.

Answer (score 2):

As you said the validation rule like the 'Message' field or all of these three ('date','time','venue') have to be filled. So the rules should look like below.

```
$rules = [
            'date'    => 'required_with_all:time,venue|required_without:message',
            'time'    => 'required_with_all:date,venue|required_without:message',
            'venue'   => 'required_with_all:date,time |required_without:message',
            'message' => 'required_without_all:date,time,venue',
            ];
```