# 'required_if' validation alongside database check in Laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-validation

I am implementing a **survey builder with several allowed question types**. These types are:

1. Single choice
2. Multiple choice
3. Star rating

The **1.** and **2.** require *multiple possible answers* to be given by a user, whereas the **3.** *does not require any possible answers at all*. These requirements are stored as `true` / `false` values in `question_types.multiple_answers` column.

I need a validation rule, that will:

**require** `answers[]` array to be present in the request, **only if** the selected `question_type's` corresponding `multiple_answers` value **is set to true in the database**.

---

Here is an illustration of what I'm trying to achieve:

```php
...->validate($request, [
    'answers' => 'require_if:type,...' // <-- if 'type' has 'multiple_answers' set to true in database
]);
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37935804/laravel-form-validation-with-logic-operators/38141214#38141214 this might help you..

Comment: @Avishek thank you, but this is a different case. I need to **check a condition in the database and require fields based on that**.

Comment: is that means you want to add `required fields` base on the `not null` columns of database..?

Comment: Yes, I want a validation to check existing entries in database and make a decision based on that

Comment: Why dont you create a dynamic rules in the controller : `$rules = []; if(multi_answers){ $rules = [ 'answers'    => 'required'] } else {//other thing}`

Comment: @Maraboc I've considered and discarded that option due to it's sloppiness. But, in the end it gets the job done

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create [conditional validation rules](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/validation#conditionally-adding-rules) to do what you want. The rule specified as the second parameter will only be evaluated if the function specified as the third parameter returns true.

```
$v->sometimes('answers', 'required', function($input) {
    // check database and return true if multiple_answers is set for the type ($input->type)
});
```